# Calendar giving wrong date and time

Tags: android, android-calendar, android-datepicker

This is a very annoying issue I've been facing for a few days now. I'm using the Genymotion emulator. The code is as follows:

```
        DatePicker dp = (DatePicker) d.findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
        TimePicker tp = (TimePicker) d.findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);

        Calendar.getInstance();

        selectedDate = Calendar.YEAR + "/" + Calendar.MONTH + "/" + Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH;
        selectedTime = Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY + ":" + Calendar.MINUTE;

        dp.init(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, new OnDateChangedListener()
        {
            @Override public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
            {
                selectedDate = dayOfMonth + "/" + monthOfYear + 1 + "/" + year;
            }
        });
```

When I debug the above code and watch the values of **Calendar.MONTH** and **Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH**, they're wrong. Same goes for hour and minute values (current time is 17:25 but the Calendar gives 11:12).

What am I doing wrong? TimerPicker is initialized to the correct time on the same device, automatically.

Comment: Does the same happen when you run it on a physical device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` is a constant assigned by Android.

When you use `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` it doesn't give you the current hour it gives you the value that Android assigned to constant `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY`

If you want to get the current time you need to do

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
```

and then if you want to retrieve the current hour retrieve it like

```
cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

This will give you the current hour same goes for any other value.

**Note:**  When you retrieve MONTH it will give you 1 less value For eg. for May it will return 4 because it is based on 0 index value.

So in order to get today's date and time you have to do

```
selectedDate = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "/" + (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) + "/" + cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
selectedTime = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

Comment: Thanks :) I had fixed it myself but didn't wanna delete the question since it could be helpful to someone else. Marked correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    selectedDate = cal.YEAR + "/" + cal .MONTH + "/" + cal.DAY_OF_MONTH;
    selectedTime = cal.HOUR_OF_DAY + ":" + cal.MINUTE;

    dp.init(cal.YEAR, cal.MONTH, cal.DAY_OF_MONTH, new OnDateChangedListener()
    {
        @Override public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
        {
            selectedDate = dayOfMonth + "/" + monthOfYear + 1 + "/" + year;
        }
    });
```

Comment: What exactly did you change? Can you explain what is different and why? Its more helpful to beginners if you offer some sort of explanation about your proposed answer

Comment: This is wrong because you are still referring to the `Constants` assigned by `Android` not getting the actual values.

Comment: I changed Calendar object to Calendar's getInstance method which  returns a calendar whose locale is based on system settings and whose time fields have been initialized with the current date and time

Comment: Did you try running it? Because i am pretty sure it won't return the correct time. Even though you created an object of `Calendar`, `HOUR_OF_DAY` still refers to the same value because it is a `static int`. You can check it here [HOUR_OF_DAY](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR_OF_DAY)